# URL-Rewrite in .htaccess RegEx

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am wondering how to set up a RegEx to rewrite a specific url so it seems like the requested site is in a specific folder. I tried it with manual RewriteRules, but having issues when using a "/" within the rewritten name...
(This is question #2: Why can't i use "/" in rewritten names?)

I have files named like:

ga_filename.php
or
gt_filename.php

These files are physically all in one directory.

The current url is something like

www.whatever.de/index.php?content=ga_filename.php

So corresponding to the 2 starting letters of my files (ga or gt) i want the url to look like

www.whatever.de/ga/filename
or
www.whatever.de/gt/filename

What i need is a RegEx that reads the first 2 letters after the "=" (from ?content=), creates the corresponding folder, and takes the rest of the filename after the "_" (from ga_filename.php) with .php removed as the shown filename in the url.

I hope i have explained this understandable..
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:index\.php)?\?content=(\w{2})_([^\s&.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1_$2.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I forgot to mention, that these files are included to the index.php
so the actual url is like
www.whatever.de/index.php?content=ga_filename.php

I edited my question regarding.

Comment: this actually shows just my index.php, but without any includes and all formating css and images is missing

Comment: image/css/js problem is due to your use of relative paths. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?content=$1_$2.php [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I forgot to mention, that these files are included to the index.php
so the actual url is like
www.whatever.de/index.php?content=ga_filename.php

I edited my question regarding.